# Auto delete instances of a collection like std:list or std::vector?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a collection of pointers, for example `std::vector<std::string*>`.

Which is the most appropriate way to automatically delete the instances pointed by its items when the collection is deleted?

When I delete the collection, I would automatically like to delete all pointed items.

Comment: By instance, do you mean instance or pointer to instance? I.e. `std::vector<std::string>` or `std::vector<std::string*>`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cleaning up an STL list/vector of pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307082/cleaning-up-an-stl-list-vector-of-pointers)

Answer (score 9):

The simplest way to ensure the container's elements are correctly destroyed is to store objects, not pointers.

If you really need pointers (perhaps for polymorphism), then store smart pointers - usually `std::unique_ptr`, but perhaps `std::shared_ptr` (or its TR1 or Boost equivalents) if you need to share ownership, or are stuck with a pre-2011 compiler.

Don't try to juggle raw pointers - that's a recipe for memory leaks and worse.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? I'd like to correct the answer if I got something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::shared_ptr` (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr))

Example:

```
class A { ... };

{
    std::list<std::shared_ptr<A>> data;
    data.push_back(std::make_shared<A>()); // add element to the list
}
// at this point data is deleted and all created class instanced with it
```

Another way is to use proper [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization). This means that the class destructor is responsible to delete all acquired resources. Than you can store instanced per value in your container.

Answer (score 1):

The items are automatically deleted.

For example, for `std::vector<std::string>`, the destructor of each instance of `std::string` will be called.

If you asked about **pointers to instances**, C++ pointers don't have destructors.